# How to set edittext field only for entering alphabets in Android?

Tags: android

Hii
    How to set edittext field only for entering alphabets in Android?

Answer (score 2):

declare

```
android:inputType="text"
```

in layout.xml file

Comment: but adding this I can enter number also

Comment: required to enter only alphabets is the question. your answer is able to enter numbers also